# Auto generated row for html table

Tags: php, html

I have 100,000 records in MySQL database. I want to generate a table automatically to display. this is the code that I have done. The automated row is generated but still have errors. I need your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>Random 10 - Random Packet Sampling</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

 <style type="text/css">

.style1 {color: #FFFFFF}
.style109 {font-size: 12px}
.style115 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style118 {font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style3 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style8 {color: #000000}
.style9 {color: #FF0000}
-->
  </style>

 </head>

<body>
 <?php
include_once ("connection.php");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trying");
$result = array();


while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    array_push($result, array('no'=> $data2['no'],
                            'time'=> $data2['time'],
                          'source'=> $data2['source'],
                      'destination'=>$data2['destination'],
                          ));
$rand = array();
$step = 10;

for ($min = 0; $min <= 49; $min = $min + $step)
{   
    $max = $min + $step;
    $rand[] = $result[rand($min,$max)];
}
//echo json_encode($rand);


?>

<h1>Random Packet Sampling</h1>
<h2>Random 10</h2>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table width="980" id="rounded-corner">
        <thead>
          <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
            <th width="34" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rounded-company"><div align="center"><strong><span class="style33 style115">No.</span></strong></div></th>
        <th width="108" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center"><strong><span     class="style33 style115">No</span></strong></div></th>
            <th width="241" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center"><strong><span     class="style33 style115">Time</span></strong></div></th>
            <th width="224" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center"><strong><span     class="style33 style115">Sourc</span></strong></div></th>
            <th width="156" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center"><strong><span     class="style33 style115">Destination</span></strong></div></th>
             <!--<th width="100" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center">    <strong><span class="style33 style115">Mark</span></strong></div></th>-->
          </tr></thead>

          <?php $i = 0;
                $c=1;
                do { ?>
          <tr bgcolor="#FFF9CE">
            <td height="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center" class="style8"><span     class="style118">
              <?php
                              if($page>0){
                              $x=($page*10)+$c;
                              }else{$x=$c;}


                              ?>
            <?php echo $x?></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center" class="style8"><span     class="style30 style61 "><?php echo $rand[0]; ?></a></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center" class="style109 style8"><span     class="style30 style61 "><?php echo $rand[1]; ?></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center" class="style109     style8"><span class="style30 style61 "><?php echo $rand[2]; ?></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center" class="style109 style8"><span     class="style30 style61 "><?php echo $rand[3]; ?></span></div></td>


            </tr>
          <?php $c++; } while (count($rand)); ?>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="rounded-foot-left"><?php
            echo count ($rand); echo records;


            ?></td>
            <td width="188" class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>


</body>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your code is missing the `</html>` tag - *just saying*.

Comment: How are you defining `$page`?

Comment: Fred-ii- , I have declare the </html> also the $page. however the only problem now is I have an error in displaying the data. The error is "array to string conversion".

Comment: That's most likely why. `$page` isn't defined anywhere, you're just doing an `if...` and it's looking for `$page=???` somewhere. Least, that's what I make of it.

Comment: yes, i have declare the $page = 0. The data for <?php echo ($rand)?> gave the error. I tried to replace the echo to print_r however, it print all the values insides the array. Do you have any site for me to refer in order to display each value of the array which is stored in the $rand array. Sorry, i am still a newbie for this language.

Comment: Something like this could work `$i=1; foreach($rand as $k=>$v){ echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">Value is: '. $v .'<div>'; $i++; }` and this page could help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm